# Objective C - Completion blocks and view controllers being popped off stack

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I've written a asynchronous call that has a completion block to return a UIImage, then in the completion block the view controller sets a UIImageView to use that image. My question is what happens if that view controller is popped off UINavigationController stack and is no longer alive before the completion block executes?

```
[MyAPI getImage:imageID completionBlock:^(MyAPIStatus status, id result) {
        if (status == kSuccessful) {
            self.ImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the block passed to your API captures(retains) `self`, `self` will be alive.
So if you use retain/release properly or use ARC, this is harmless.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  Your API should probably have another method to cancel the asynchronous task that you can call when the view controller is deallocated.